# How to deserialize JSON objects to List<> when the items are not in a Json array? (C#)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using a Json string from another system.  It looks something like this:

```
{
  "BoolValue": true,
  "Inventory": {
    "Item1": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Item One"
    },
    "Item2": {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Item Two"
    },
    "Item3": {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Item Three"
    }
  }
}
```

How would I deserialize the "Item" objects to a List?
I know it's easy then the json uses an array for "Inventory": [] but how will I do it when it's just object after object under the Inventory property?

Comment: are you looking for what classes you'll need, or how to deserialize into your classes?

Comment: The values shown under each item won't work for a `List`; they have a key/value structure. You'll need a hash table of some type like a `Dictionary<T>`. Either way, in order to deserialize you'll need a class definition for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you'll need a class setup like this:

```
public class Results {
    public bool BoolValue { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Item> Inventory { get; set; }
}

public class Item {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```